# Force initialize on ViewController in UIPageViewContoller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Im using a page based application very similar to the standard template from apple (page based app). I want all the pages to be loaded and kept in memory at start up, but it doesnt work. I keep all the `ViewControllers` that `UIPageViewController` displays in an `NSArray` which I initiate. The problem is that the `ViewControllers` are not initilized until the `PageViewController` calls them. How do I force initiation of `ViewControllers` right here in the init method of the `ModelController`.

```
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *historyViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HistoryViewController"];
    historyViewController.restorationIdentifier= HistoryRestorationID;
    UIViewController *totalViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TotalViewSlidingController"];
    totalViewController.restorationIdentifier= TotalRestorationID;
    PlugTableViewController *plugViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlugSlidingViewController"];
    plugViewController.restorationIdentifier= PlugRestorationID;

    //Force initiation of ViewController here!

    pages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:historyViewController,totalViewController,plugViewController, nil];

}
return self;
```

}

The reason why I want to initiate them directly, is because they take time to initiate.

Comment: Can't you move out the initialization code to a separate class (i.e. like a [View Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel))?

Comment: Maybe I could, the reason why initialization takes time is because I need to call a WebService. So the best thing would be to use something like CoreData to store this information. However, now I just need a quick fix for this.

Comment: When in your view controller is your initialization code run? In `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: No, thats my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The view hierarchy is not loaded until someone references its view property.
Try call `[historyViewController view]` or read `historyViewController.view`. It should do the job.

Comment: I have tried that before. Tried it again now, but didnt work.

Comment: The best way to make it works it's add it as a subview to your viewController view. And after that add it to the array. You can also try call [[historyViewController view] setNeedsDisplay] but I'm not 100% sure it will work.

Comment: setNeedsDisplay didnt work. I have 3 pages, horizantally scrollable, where do you mean i should add it as a subview? To another page?

Comment: Add it to the first page but set transparent to 0.

Comment: Ok I understand, that will work. But its a really ugly solution. This cant be the only solution?

Comment: I would create this view controller programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try type-casting the object where you want to use this view, hopefully this will do the job.

`PlugTableViewController *plugView=(PlugTableViewController *)[pages objectAtIndex:3];`

And one more things, try to change the code

```
UIViewController *historyViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HistoryViewController"];
```

to

```
HistoryViewController *historyViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HistoryViewController"];
```

hopefully you have made a header class `HistoryViewController` but you are initlizing view by `UIViewController`

Another possible solution is to pre-load data instead of viewcontroller as view controller do not take time to load.

MOST UNRECOMMENDED way is to add all view as subview and keep them hidden, show them when you need them.

Comment: The problem is not that I want to use the object (or NSArray). I just want the pages to load at start up. I tried both of your suggestions, but the ViewController wont load until UIPageViewController asks for it.

Comment: I could not understand your business logic, but as long as I understood is that you are doing some webrequests/someCalculations on these pages and you want that when you go on these pages, all data should be there with no time. am I right?

Comment: Yes correct. The best way would be to load these in a local database like CoreData, but will do that later.

Comment: Then you are doing it in wrong way, no function other than -(id)init of these viewcontroller is called. you have to make NSobject classes or do all the calculation in base class and store it globally or wherever you want. viewcontroller initiation and loading stored data will not take to much time.

Comment: Yes, thats what I said. The best way is to load these to something like CoreData. And no youre wrong, -(id)init or -(void)viewDidLoad is not called in my example. Thats the whole problem im trying to get help with.

Comment: -(id)init is called when you call [[viewcontroller alloc] init];
and Viewdidload is called when you call addsubview or pushviewcontroller.